# split big dataframe into multiple ones under condition

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe of 453627 rows like :

```
number  action
1        34
34       2
45       1
42       0
33       3
3        4
```

I need to split it to 2000 row each, but if total action sum reaches 5000 I split it till that

example: if sum of actions column reaches 5000 at row 1200 split the dataframe to that row, if no split it to row 2000 and so on

how can I do so?

also, how can I read multiple CSVs files in folder each in individual dataframe?

Comment: Do a `for` loop. There are some questions on stackoverflow on how to split data on threshold sum.

Comment: give me an example

Comment: You can specify a mapping or a function to group by, you should be able to craft a function for at least the `cumsum` portion of your requirement. : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby

Comment: One part of your requirement isn't clear: if the first split occurs at *row* 1200 because of the `cumsum` is the row *limit* for the second split at row 3200?

Comment: no let me be clear , i need to split the big dataframe to small ones of 2000 rows , but if the cumsum of action reaches the threshold before 2000 , lets say 1200 , the dataframe will be 1200 , and the second split start again if it reaches threshold at 100 ok it will be 100 rows if no till 2000 it will be 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine a vectorized way, so I would just iterate the `action` column to produce a Series with a distinct value per slot.

After that, a mere groupby would be enough to split the initial dataframe:

```
maxlen = 2000
thresh = 5000
cursum = 0
curlen = 0
curval = 0
arr = df['action'].values
cat = np.zeros(len(arr), int)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    curlen += 1
    cursum += arr[i]
    if curlen != 1 and (curlen >= maxlen or cursum >= thresh):
        cursum = 0
        curlen = 0
        curval += 1
    cat[i] = curval
cat = pd.Series(cat, df.index)

dfs = [dg for _, dg in df.groupby(cat)]
```

dfs contains the list of the splitted dataframe